# Why "GELU" activation function is used instead of ReLu in BERT?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

The activation function **Gaussian Error Linear Units(GELUs)** is used in the popular NLP model ***BERT***. Is there any solid reason ?

Answer (score 14):

It is not known why certain activation functions work better than others in different contexts. So the only answer for "why use GELU instead of ReLu" is "because it works better"

Edit: there is some explanation possible, see [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20230324020355/https://chadrick-kwag.net/relu-gelu-swish-mish-activation-function-comparison/). `relu` can suffer from "problems where significant amount of neuron in the network become zero and don’t practically do anything." `gelu` is smoother near zero and "is differentiable in all ranges, and allows to have gradients(although small) in negative range" which helps with this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the blog has gone 404.

Answer (score 8):

GELU is a smoother version of the RELU.

ReLU vs GELU:

[image]

I think the reason is stated in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.08415.pdf#page=6):

[image]